# How can I delete a user in linux when the system says its currently used in a process

Tags: linux

I am trying to delete a user I created on ubuntu.

However when I use the following command:

```
userdel -r cafe_fixer
```

I get the following message:

```
user cafe_fixer is currently used by process 15945
```

I am not using this user for anything I just created it and now wish to delete it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First use `pkill` or `kill -9 <pid>` to kill the process.

Then use following `userdel` command to delete user,

```
userdel -f cafe_fixer
```

According to `userdel` man page:

> -f, --force
>
> This option forces the removal of the user account, even if the user
> is still logged in. It also forces userdel to remove the user's home
> directory and mail spool, even if another user uses the same home
> directory or if the mail spool is not owned by the specified user. If
> USERGROUPS_ENAB is defined to yes in /etc/login.defs and if a group
> exists with the same name as the deleted user, then this group will be
> removed, even if it is still the primary group of another user.

Edit 1:

**Note: This option (i.e. `--force`) is dangerous and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.**

Edit 2:

In spite of the description about some files, this key allows removing the user while it is in use. Don't forget to `chdir /` before, because this command will also remove home directory.

Comment: Thanks Skynet, I tried it but when I do this I get the following message:userdel: user cafe_fixer is currently used by process 15945
userdel: cannot open /etc/subuid

Comment: better kill that process by `pkill` or `kill -9 <pid>` then run whichever you choose, until unless you terminating the process it will not let you delete the user.

Comment: That did it. I stopped the process and then deleted the user with userdel -f cafe_fixer

Comment: Note that the `userdel` man page also says the following about the `--force` option: **"Note: This option is dangerous and may leave your system in an inconsistent state."**

Comment: Is there a way to see what the process is?  I have this same problem and I am trying to figure out if I kill it, will I have a negative effect.

Comment: @Bokai to see all current process that's running in your system you can always use `ps` command.

Comment: In spite of the description about some files, this key allows removing the user while it is in use. Don't forget to `chdir /` before, because this command will also remove home directory. @skynet, please add a note about chdir.

Comment: That did not work for me since the user started a new process right after I've removed the previous one. Refer to my answer for more information.

Answer (score 51):

## Only solution that worked for me

```
$ sudo killall -u username && sudo deluser --remove-home -f username
```

The `killall` command is used if multiple processes are used by the user you want to delete.

The `-f` option forces the removal of the user account, even if the user is still logged in. It also forces `deluser` to remove the user's home directory and mail spool, even if another user uses the same home directory.

Comment: I never encountered issues using the `-f` option. In my opinion, it is safe, just do not delete important users.

Comment: As root user: I did: `killall -u username` then `deluser --remove-home username`. Your solution was the only one here that worked for me. 

Edit: Umm... my home folder stayed. I removed that (as root) in /home/username using `rm -rf username/` in when in the /home folder).

Comment: @wlwl2 Did you use the `-f` option when removing the user home directory?

Comment: This worked for me but I need an additional `-9` for `killall`.

Answer (score 5):

```
pkill  <process id>
userdel <username>
```

Answer (score 3):

restart your computer and run $sudo deluser username... worked for me

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score -1):

It worked i used
userdell --force USERNAME
Some times eventhough -f and --force is same -f is not working sometimes
After i removed the account i exit back to that removed username which i removed from root then what happened is this

[image: image description here]