# Gcloud how to reset password for rstudio VM instance

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, rstudio, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I created a VM instance on gcloud hosting Rstudio. However, after a month of not using the server I forgot the password of the VM instance and not sure if I'm using the right user name. When I tried to login by external IP:8787 the credentials that I remember are not valid.  Does anyone know how to recover password and username for VM instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect to your rstudio Vm via SSH and then you will be able to choose new password by following these steps:

- Go to your [VM instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.9995189.-1023965820.1522686217&_gac=1.251405874.1523049036.EAIaIQobChMI1Mu-4sem2gIVkoF-Ch0ssAz8EAAYASAAEgJZcfD_BwE) and in the list of virtual machine instances, click SSH in the row of the instance that you want to connect to.

When you log-in your VM via SSH:

1) Run the command **sudo passwd < YOUR_USERNAME >**  (Keep in mind by default the admin username is rstudio-user) .

2) Type the new password and then retype it and done.

3) Try to connect to your VM with your new password

Moreover, if you are not using the default username or you forget, you can run 
**sudo cat /etc/passwd** to see the username when you logged in to your VM via SSH.

Comment: Is there way to recover username? I can't believe I forgot everything within a week.

Comment: The answer has been edited since you forget your username and you are not using the default username.

Comment: How do I remove an user?

Comment: While I was waiting for the answer I went ahead created a new user and installed packages under that user, but now I have recovered password I hope to remove the user to save memory.

Comment: You can remove the user from your linux machine.This will revoke the user's SSH access, and remove that user's file and directory ownership by following these commands: sudo userdel USER'S USERNAME. do not forget to replace the username that you want to remove with USER'S USERNAME as I mentioned above. you can take a look at these following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103045/how-can-i-delete-a-user-in-linux-when-the-system-says-its-currently-used-in-a-pr) to how to remove a user.